# Проблема с Tomcat и Servlet

Tags: java, веб-программирование, tomcat, servlet

Есть простой сервлет

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String s = "<html>" +"<header><title>This is title</title></header>" + "<body>" + "Hello World" + "</body>" + "/html";
        resp.getWriter().write(s);
    }
}
```

после запуска выдаёт такую фигню
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя везде стоит utf-8, уже всё перепробовал, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас сервлет имеет маппинг `/hello`, а вы открываете `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет это $END$ находится в index.jsp зайдите в WEB и  index.jsp и вам остается только писать логику в index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

В конфигурации запуска проекта в верхнем правом углу в IDEA "Edit configurations", там прописана стартовая страница просто localhost:8080, потому и читается index.jsp. Нужно дописать адрес страницы и все должно работать.